# Node.js Readline, get the current line number

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following implementation where everything works but this line:

```
lineNumber: line.lineNumber
```

this line returns undefined, I am adding a full fragment of code below, my question is: Does Readline provide a standard way to get the  line number somehow? Or I have to implement my counter to keep track of the line number, which would be simple but I don't want if there's a standard way of doing it?

```
/**
* Search for occurrences of the specified pattern in the received list of files.
* @param filesToSearch - the list of files to search for the pattern
* @returns {Promise} - resolves with the information about the encountered matches for the pattern specified.
*/
const findPattern = (filesToSearch) => {
console.log(filesToSearch);
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 var results = [ ];
 // iterate over the files
 for(let theFile of filesToSearch){
  let dataStream = fs.createReadStream(theFile);
  let lineReader = readLine.createInterface({
    input: dataStream
  });

  let count = 0; // this would do the trick but I'd rather use standard approach if there's one
  // iterates over each line of the current file
  lineReader.on('line',(line) => {
    count++;
    if(line.indexOf(searchPattern) > 0) {
      let currLine = line.toString();
      currLine = currLine.replace(/{/g, '');//cleanup { from string if present
      results.push({
        fileName: theFile,
        value: currLine,
        lineNumber: line.lineNumber //HERE: this results undefined
        //lineNumber: count // this does the trick but I'd rather use standard approach.
      });
    }
  });

   // resolve the promise once the file scan is finished.
   lineReader.on('close', () => resolve(results));
  }
 });
};
```

Answer (score 23):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to find the line number using the `readline` node module, however, using ES6 it isn't difficult to roll your own counter in one line of code.

```
const line_counter = ((i = 0) => () => ++i)();
```

When we create the callback function we simply default the second parameter to the `line_counter` function, and we can act as though the **line** and the **line number** are both being passed when a `line` event occurs.

```
rl.on("line", (line, lineno = line_counter()) => {
  console.log(lineno); //1...2...3...10...100...etc
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply, using a variable increment together with foo(data, ++i) it will always pass the number of the new line to the function.

```
let i = 0
const stream = fs.createReadStream(yourFileName)
stream.pipe().on("data", (data) => foo(data, ++i))

const foo = (data, line) => {
  consle.log("Data: ", data)
  consle.log("Line number:", line)
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation of your code would be preferred.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: adding comment to help other people in the future. :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the lineno param if you are using [node linereader](https://github.com/nswbmw/node-linereader)

```
lineReader.on('line', function (lineno, line) {
    if(line.indexOf(searchPattern) > 0) {
          let currLine = line.toString();
          currLine = currLine.replace(/{/g, '');//cleanup { from string if present
          results.push({
            fileName: theFile,
            value: currLine,
            lineNumber: lineno 
          });
     }
});
```

Comment: Hi, this looks nice, thank you however I am using standard Node.js approach: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line and I don't want or will add a new dependency just to have the line number, I'd rather use the custom counter that already works, I was just expecting that the standard library would have something built in like the lib you just mentioned.